# why class can call the no static function?

Tags: cocos2d-x

```
bool GameOverLayer::init()
{
    if (CCLayerColor::initWithColor(ccc4(255, 255, 255, 255))) {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

the function initWithColor isnot static function , why i can  called it with cclayercolor?

```
define initWithColor function as below code :
bool CCLayerColor::initWithColor(const ccColor4B& color)
{
   CCSize s = CCDirector::sharedDirector()->getWinSize();
   this->initWithColor(color, s.width, s.height);
   return true;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GameOverLayer is inherited from CCLayerColor and initWithColor function is public and non-static so in code you can use this statement:

```
CCLayerColor::initWithColor(ccc4(255,255,255,255));
```

that means call inherited function from selected parent.
if you don't like this type of calling you can use:

```
this->initWithColor(ccc4(255,255,255,255));
```

if you like to know more about this type of programming read more about inheritance and multiple inheritance. you can start in [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/inheritance/) and [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_inheritance.htm)